# Calling a function on every column of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, for-loop, numpy, pandas

I would like to compare the difference in mean between two samples, distinguished by the variable `sample` in the following pandas `DataFrame`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sample': np.random.choice([1, 2], 10, replace=True),
                   'x': np.random.uniform(size=100),
                   'y': np.random.normal(size=100),
                   'z': np.random.choice([1,5,7,3,9],100, replace=True})
```

After importing

```
from scipy import stats
```

I would like to use the function

```
 stats.ttest_ind(s1, s2, equal_var = False)
```

on each column `z` in `df` such that `s1=df['sample'==1, z]` corresponds to the subset of the column from sample 1, and  `s2=df['sample'==2, z]` corresponds to the subset of `z` in sample 2.

For one variable, I can used:

```
stats.ttest_ind(df.ix[df['sample']==1, 'x'], df.ix[df['sample']==2, 'x'], equal_var= False)
```

I am looking for a way to do this for all the columns at once. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a For Loop on df.columns

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame({'sample': np.random.choice([1, 2], 100, replace=True),
                   'x': np.random.uniform(size=100),
                   'y': np.random.normal(size=100),
                   'z': np.random.choice([1,5,7,3,9],100, replace=True)})

def ttest(x):
    y = stats.ttest_ind(df.ix[df['sample']==1, x], 
        df.ix[df['sample']==2, x], 
        equal_var= False)
    return y


for col in df.columns:
    print col, ttest(col)
```

output:

```
sample (-inf, 0.0)
x (0.051257527331014435, 0.95922494541232151)
y (-1.8814017903969658, 0.063320355499510511)
z (-1.0033063682017582, 0.31819256215047681)
```